# How to schedule DAG tasks once the DAG has been triggered?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using the TriggerDagRunOperator so that one controller DAG may trigger a target DAG.  However, once the controller DAG triggers the target DAG, the target DAG switches to "running", but none of its tasks are scheduled.  I would like for the target DAG's tasks to be scheduled as soon as the target DAG is triggered by the controller DAG.

```py
# Controller DAG's callable
def conditionally_trigger(context, dag_run_object):
   condition_param = context['params']['condition_param']
   if condition_param:
      return dag_run_obj
   return None

# Target DAG's callable
def say_hello():
   print("Hello")

# Controller DAG
controller_dag = DAG(
   dag_id="controller",
   default_args = {
      "owner":"Patrick Stump",
      "start_date":datetime.utcnow(),
   },
   schedule_interval='@once',
)

# Target DAG
target_dag = DAG(
   dag_id="target",
   default_args = {
      "owner":"Patrick Stump",
      "start_date":datetime.utcnow(),
   },
   schedule_interval=None,
)

# Controller DAG's task
controller_task = TriggerDagRunOperator(
   task_id="trigger_dag",
   trigger_dag_id="target",
   python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
   params={'condition_param':True},
   dag=controller_dag,
)

# Target DAG's task -- never scheduled!
target_task = PythonOperator(
   task_id="print_hello",
   python_callable=say_hello,
   dag=target_dag,
)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be using a dynamic start date like this: `"start_date":datetime.utcnow(),`

I would rename the dags, and give them a start date like 2019-01-01, and then try again.

The scheduler reads DAGs repeatedly, and when the start date changes every time the DAG is parsed (`utcnow()` will evaluate to a new value every time), unexpected things can happen.

[Here is some further reading on start_date.](http://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date)